# trouble with end in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a server without express. Identify the url and then answer with a html.

if the url is '/' the response is index.html and if the url is '/bio' the response is bio.html

The problem is when I want to go back to '/' and get index after '/bio'

```
http.createServer(function (req,res){
  var pathName = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
  console.log(pathName);

  if(pathName === '/bio'){
    fs.readFile("./bio.html", function (a, bio){
      res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
      res.write(bio);
      res.end();
    });
  };

  fs.readFile('./index.html', function(err, index){
    console.log(req.url);
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    res.write(index);
    res.end();
  });

}).listen(8888);
```

When should I end the response?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: In all cases you're serving index.html, put a `return` keyword before `fs.readFile("./bio....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you should allow only one code branch to call `res.end()`.

In your case, the code should look like this

```
if(pathName === '/bio'){
  fs.readFile("./bio.html", function (a, bio){
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    res.write(bio);
    res.end();
  });
}
else {
  fs.readFile('./index.html', function(err, index){
    console.log(req.url);
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    res.write(index);
    res.end();
  });
}
```

I would recommend introducing a generic static file handler:

```
// assuming we have access to the current `res` object
function serveStatic(filePath, callback) {
  fs.readFile(filePath, function () {
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    res.write(bio);
    res.end();

    callback();
  })
}

var filePath;
if(pathName === '/bio') {
  filePath = './bio.html';
}
else {
  filePath = './index.html';
}

serveStatic(filePath, function () {
  console.log('Done!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need stop the flow while sending response try `return res.end()` in place of `res.end()`.

Comment: Agree! The async nature of NodeJS can make maintainers crazy. It should help us a lot by an explicit `return`. If you feel that it's just awkward to return `res.end()`, you may do a return immediately after `res.end()`.